# Unexplained last few lines of a PDF

Tags: pdf

This is a massive long shot, but I'm giving it a go anyway.

I'm reverse-engineering part of a daemon of a scanner, since it was never compiled for the architecture I require it on, and the producer has dropped support. As part of this process, I'm reading a PDF file directly from a TCP socket.

After filtering out a few control bytes that appear in and around the PDF file, I believe I have succesfully extracted the file from the data stream. However, the end of file still displays a slight corruption (the yellow-to-black gradient). I guess it's better illustrated with an image:

[image: last few lines of the pdf]

I recall seeing this a while ago, but I do not recall the context.. Is this a broader problem that sometimes happens in PDFs when you missconfigure a parameter?

Is this perhaps an indicator that I am providing less content than one of the headers promises I will?

Comment: Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: It looks like a bitmap ran out of bounds. Damaged bitmaps are usually not fatal errors in a PDF; a good viewer will plod on. A sample file would indeed be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I should've provided a sample file. Unfortunately, the only record I have is of a file that I cannot upload, and I'm currently not near the scanner to produce a sample.. I'll add a file as soon as I can (but that might even be monday). In the mean time, thanks for the bitmap suggestion! Looking into that now.

Comment: @Jongware turns out it was indeed caused by a damaged bitmap! I had accidently left two bytes of protocol data in the PDF. This caused a bitmap to overflow its bounds. Stripping the control bytes fixed the PDF, and as it turns out, this was the last bit of corruption! If you want to add your comment as an answer, I can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bitmap ran out of bounds. Damaged bitmaps are usually not fatal errors in a PDF; a good viewer will plod on nevertheless.